# Enable all msg of specific node(ECU) by CAPL function 'TestEnableMsgAllTx'

Tags: can-bus, capl

I tried to use the function 'TestEnableMsgAllTx(char node[])' to enable messages of node 'EMS', but this library function looks does not work.

### There is my code and error text as below.

1) enable code

```
export void EnableAll_EMSMsg()
{
  testEnableMsgAllTx("EMS");
}
```

2)error text

### TestEnableMsgAllTx: No node handle could be found for node EMS.   error in test system

There is a node which named 'EMS' but it does not work.
Is there anybody who use this function to enable all messages of some node?

I add a screenshot of simulation setup.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F6n4.png)

Comment: Is the node placed in the simulation setup? Does it have the CANoe Interaction Layer assigned?

Comment: Yes, EMS node is already in the simulation setup, and CANoe Interaction layer is assigned. TestDisableMsg(msgName) is working, but that function has parameter as node does not work.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your simulation setup? Do you have multiple busses?

Comment: I add a screenshot of simulation setup. And I have multiple bus.

Comment: You could try to call `setBusContext(GetBusNameContext("VCAN"));` before your call to `testEnableMsgAllTx`

Comment: @M.Spiller, thank you so much dear, it is working after call setBusContext(GetBusNameContext("VCAN")); !
I appreciate your kind and continuous attention. If you make answer for this, I will choose it.

Comment: @M.Spiller, 1 more question, is there a function to enable all Tx msg in specific channel?(for example, VCAN)

Comment: Added as an answer. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a method to enable all messages of a channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there is a node with the name `EMS` in the simulation setup and it has the CANoe interaction layer assigned.

In case you have multiple busses you might have to switch the bus context first:

```
setBusContext(GetBusNameContext("VCAN"));
```